# CORS settings in Java Play 2.4.x

Tags: java, cors, playframework-2.4

I have a some issue using play 2.4.x setting CORS. I am using play to store and retrieve image files. When I access the image 'http://localhost:9000/assets/images/favicon.png' of play, on a plain native test.html file using javascript, it throws CORS security error.

I did the following:
In play - 
**Application.conf** file I added

```
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

In **Filter.java** file (In root directory)

```
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.HttpFilters;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    CORSFilter corsFilter;

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[] { corsFilter };
    }
}
```

In **build.sbt** file

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  filters
)
```

My javascript code in html file where I am trying to load image on to a canvas:

```
$("#test").recScribble.loadImage('http://localhost:9000/assets/images/favicon.png');
```

My recScribble plugin has a loadImage function as below with canvas context as ctx

```
$.fn.recScribble.loadImage=function(imgSrc){ //to Load image on to the canvas; give the link as parameter
        var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            imageObj.src =imgSrc;
            imageObj.onload = function() {
                canvas.width=imageObj.naturalWidth;
                canvas.height=imageObj.naturalHeight;
                ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
              };
            return this;
        };
```

The HTML returns CORS security error with following information

**General**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/assets/images/favicon.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:[::1]:9000
```

**Response Header**

```
Content-Length:0
Date:Sat, 12 Dec 2015 02:35:47 GMT
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
```

Loading image using the same HTML file is working when I am accessing image from other server (on Internet)  where CORS is properly enabled. So I am guessing, there is no issue with javascript (But not sure).

I am new to play and don't know which setting to change here. Pls. help!